# PHP's automatic string conversion

Tags: php

I couldn't find any useful explanation as to why PHP's automatic string casting is a useful feature?  To me it seems like it can cause more bugs and issues than it solves.  Not to mention the extra CPU cycles it takes to check each string if it needs to be converted.  I can't think of any examples where this functionality is beneficial but perhaps I'm not being imaginative enough or I'm to used to using method calls like atoi or python's built in int() method.

Hopefully someone on here has an idea behind the rationale for this.

Comment: @Mark: PHP is weakly-typed, not typeless.

Comment: Sorry, mixed up my terminology.

Comment: Well, it is easier for beginners to write PHP programs which is probably one of the reasons why PHP is so popular. It is certainly not the only language which uses this so called "type juggling" and it makes perfect sense for a dynamic language. Other languages which use very similar system are Ruby, Python, PERL, JavaScript so this is not at all a bad or "weird" feature. There are few guidelines and general rules which if you follow you will have no problem with this.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP wasn't built around concepts such as "logic" or "design"; it just sort of "growed" into something intended to be easy to use. As such, some of the features either don't make sense, or have a "hacked-in" feel. This is one of them.

Comment: There's nothing "hacked in" about this. Dynamic typing predates PHP and is quite popular today in many scripting languages. Perl, for example, predates PHP by almost a decade and uses a very similar type system. So does Ruby and JavaScript which appeared around the same time.

Comment: I guess I'm just too used to languages that are statically typed.

Comment: There are plenty of dynamically, strongly-typed languages.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "string casting"? Are you talking about how numeric and string types can change dynamically based on how they're used, without explicit casts?

It's a useful feature if you don't consider strong typing important. I believe this and many of PHP's features were original implemented to make it easy to learn. It's hardly the only language that juggles types this way, and there's nothing at all wrong with it. Wikipedia lists [many languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Dynamic_typing) which a similar type system: Erlang, Groovy, JavaScript, Lisp, Lua, Objective-C, Perl, PHP, Prolog, Python, Ruby, Smalltalk and Tcl

CPU cycles and performance were the last thing on the developers mind, and maybe one PHP-based site in a million actually needs to worry about those extra cycles.

You say you're used to using `atoi`; how is *that* more useful than just treating a variable like its contents are numeric and letting the language figure out the rest?

Comment: I suppose that's very true, I didn't really think about it in terms of a learning curve.